# Append route IDs to unique stores

Tags: sql, concatenation, append

I have 8 stores that have route ids for shipment schedule. I.e: store 4552 = D1 store 4860 = D2.... I want to append the route number to all my unique stores but i have to idea how to do that for all unique values.

```
SELECT id as shipment_id, purchase_order, concat(ship_to,'-D1'), created_at, ship_on 
FROM `table1-production.warehouser_.fulfillment_orders`
WHERE reservation_id = 1730
order by (created_at) asc
```

I dont know how to write the if statement to append the route number

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yd6WL.png)

Comment: Which SQL database are you using (SQL server, Oracle, MySQL, etc.)?

Comment: `by` is not a function. Simply write `order by created_at asc`, to make code clearer.

Comment: In which table are those route ids stored?

Comment: BQ is the database

Comment: no table. I'm thinking this would need an if statement. i.e  if daiso-4552 then add D1. if daiso-4341 then add D2. Output would be daiso-4552-D1 and daiso-4341-D2

Comment: Please don’t link to images. Update your question, using editable text, to show sample data and the result you want to achieve, based on that data

Comment: understood nickW

Comment: Put the route data in a table and join to it